# Reading Shna'yim mikrah vi'echad targum aloud

Tags: halacha, torah-study, speech-talking, shnayim-mikra, thought

Does one have to actually articulate the words (dibur) of the chumash and targum (or Rashi) in order to be yoitzei the chiyuv of "shna'yim mikrah vi'echad targum" or is it enough to scan the words with your eyes (hirhur)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9PejgTqFnE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[R. Moshe Sternbauch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moishe_Sternbuch) addresses this in his Teshuvot V'hanahagot (Vol. IV #73):

> והנה לכאורה פשוט דתרגום אונקלוס צריך לקרוא בפיו דוקא ולא מספיק בהרהור, ולפ"ז אולי גם כשלומד רש"י לתרגום הדין כן, שיש להוציא בפה לצאת חובת שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום, ולא מצאתי ד"ז בפוסקים, ויש לחלק שרש"י הוה פירוש ומועיל נמי בעל פה, לא כן התרגום הוא כפשוטו, ובמקום מקרא עומד וצריך בפה כמוהו.

He writes that the verses themselves must be read aloud. Targum Onkelos must presumably be read aloud as well, and perhaps the same would apply to reading Rashi, but he is uncertain about the last point, and didn't find it in poskim.

The [Rivevot Ephraim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%98) ([Vol. VI #164](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_1084_238.pdf#xml=http://hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=238&hilite=5a2d9b48-3e0d-4891-920c-6afd628d49db&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH)) quotes R. Haim Kanievsky as opining that thinking the words does not suffice. He does not differentiate between the *mikra* and the Targum.

Hida (citing R. [Hayyyim Vital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_ben_Joseph_Vital)'s Sha'ar Hamitsvot Parashat Vaethanan) writes in [Mahzik B'rakha (OH 285:8)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=9191&st=%25u05D1%25u05E7%25u05E8%25u05D9%25u05D0%25u05EA%20%25u05D4%25u05DE%25u05E7%25u05E8%25u05D0) that one should read the verses with their cantilations, which would imply that the reading should be oral:

> כל קבל דנא צריך ליזהר בקריאת המקרא בנגינת הטעמים בשלם שבפנים

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83718/5275